# Java String some characters not showing

Tags: java

I have a problem about not showing some characters in Java.
I use Intellij to implement an example.

I have a team object shown below

```
public class Team {

    private String name;
    private int points;
    private int goalsScored;
    private int goalsAgainst;
    private int goalDifference;
}
```

I assigned some values through this code snippets shown below.

private static List getTeamStats() {
List plTeams = new ArrayList<>();

```
    plTeams.add(new Team("Team ç", 33, 27, 12));
    plTeams.add(new Team("Team ü", 32, 40, 16));
    plTeams.add(new Team("Team ğ", 30, 24, 16));
    return plTeams;
```

}

When I try to interate each one through this code shown below

plTeams.forEach(System.out::println);

I get this result.

```
Team �  ...
Team �  ...
Team �  ...
```

I also tried to use `Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"));` but it didn't help me fix  the issue.

I also tried this but nothing changed.

Help --> Edit Custom VM Options

```
-Duser.language=tr
-Duser.country=TR
-Duser.variant=TR
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're using Windows..?

Comment: @g00se I use Windows 10.

Comment: Where are you reading the result - in cmd.exe?

Comment: @g00se I only run the app in Intellij.